# (Add Google Sign-In) Why In IE(Internet Explorer)11 version Would not call "onSignIn ()" function?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-signin

I was developed a login feature.
Note the following url.

url : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

IE(Internet Explorer)10 version will operate normally. But IE(Internet Explorer)11 version does not call onSignIn () function.

```
<Html lang = "en">
  <Head>
    <Meta name = "google-signin-scope" content = "profile email">
    <Meta name = "google-signin-client_id" content = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <Script src = "https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer> </ script>
  </ Head>
  <Body>
    <Div class = "g-signin2" data-onsuccess = "onSignIn" data-theme = "dark"> </ div>
    <Script>
      function onSignIn (googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile ();
        console.log ("ID:" + profile.getId ()); // Do not send this directly to your server!
        console.log ("Name:" + profile.getName ());
        console.log ("Image URL:" + profile.getImageUrl ());
        console.log ("Email:" + profile.getEmail ());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse () id_token.;
        console.log ("ID Token:" + id_token);
      };
    </ Script>
  </ Body>
</ Html>
```

Why In IE(Internet Explorer)11 version Would not call "onSignIn ()" function?
Thank You.